# How can decrease in value of VH in px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**CODE JS:**

```
 var windowheight = $(window).outerHeight();
 var meniu= $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
 var suma=windowheight-meniu;
 $('#main-content').css('height',100+'vh' //-50px);
```

My menu has a height in pixels and I want to fall in 100vh..se can do this?

for example `(height:100vh-50px);`

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use CSS, you could do this:

```
#main-content {
    height : calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set it as `vh`, the CSS will be set. But when you try to get the computed style using `.height()`, then it will return the integral value of the height in pixels, which you can manipulate to negate 50 and re-set it to the `height` property.

Well, you can do this:

```
$('#main-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
$('#main-content').css('height', $('#main-content').height() - 50);
```